# Is there a way to check when a scroll bar appears in Javascript without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I would like to be able to detect when the vertical scroll bar appears but i don't want to use jQuery. Is there some way to do this without using jQuery?

Comment: JQuery is just JavaScript that someone else wrote to make complex tasks simpler. There is absolutely nothing you can do in JQuery that can't be done in "vanilla" JavaScript because JQuery IS JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element's `scrollHeight` is greater than its `clientHeight`.

```
const hasScrollBar = elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight;
```

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
const hasScrollBar = div.scrollHeight > div.clientHeight;
console.log(hasScrollBar);
```

```html
<div style="max-height: 100px; border: 1px solid blue; overflow: auto;">
<p>Stuff</p>
<p>Stuff</p>
<p>Stuff</p>
<p>Stuff</p>
<p>Stuff</p>
<p>Stuff</p>
<p>Stuff</p>
</div>
```

Of course, this is not the most robust solution, as you will also want to check the `overflow-y` CSS property of the element. If it is set to `scroll`, then there is always a scrollbar, but if it is set to `auto`, then the `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` will need to be checked.

```
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
const hasScrollBar = styles.overflowY === "scroll" 
            || styles.overflowY === "auto" && elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight;
```

Example with `overflow: scroll`:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("div");
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
const hasScrollBar = styles.overflowY === "scroll" 
            || styles.overflowY === "auto" && elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight;
console.log(hasScrollBar);
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: scroll; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

Example without scrollbar:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('div');
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
const hasScrollBar = styles.overflowY === "scroll" 
            || styles.overflowY === "auto" && elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight;
console.log(hasScrollBar);
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

Example with `document.scrollingElement`:

```js
const elem = document.scrollingElement;
const hasScrollBar = elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight;
console.log(hasScrollBar);
```

```html
<p style="margin-top: 500px;">Bottom</p>
```

Comment: So i should set overflow-y to auto to use this?

Comment: @Skilo83 If you do not set `overflow-y` to `auto`, there won't ever be a scrollbar because the content will just overflow visibly.

Comment: No because the element i want to detect is the body and not a div.

Comment: @Skilo83 Just use `document.body` as the element then.

Comment: parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: @Skilo83 See my last example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216785/discussion-between-skilo83-and-hev1).